# How can I make an Ada Exception visible outside a module?

Tags: exception, module, ada

I don't understand why I'm getting an error on this Ada exception.  I'm getting this error for the following example:

- Builder results: `"Send_Command_Failed" is not visible (more references follow) 1085:12`

It appears that I need to declare the exception in sample_client.ads, then the code compiles but I just find that approach to be un-modular and counter-intuitive.  So the question is really how can I do this "*right*" and export from the command_interface module.

Example client like ...

```pascal
       -- sample_client.adb --
   :
 with command_interface;
   :

 package body sample_client is 

    procedure example is

    begin
         :  ... stuff

        exception
            when Send_Command_Failed =>
                Trace_Error( "Send Exception: Send_Command_Failed at example");
            raise;           

    end example;

 end sample_client;
```

for a library interface here:

```pascal
       -- command_interface.ads --
 package command_interface

       :
     exception Send_Command_Failed;
       :

 end command_interface;
```

some code in Body can throw the Send_Command_Failed exception ...

```pascal
       -- command_interface.adb --
 package body command_interface

     : ... code raises: Send_Command_Failed
     :

 end Command_Interface; -- specification

 package body command_interface

     : ... code raises: Send_Command_Failed
     :

 end Command_Interface; -- specification
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to tell the compiler where to find the exception declaration?

```
    exception
        when command_interface.Send_Command_Failed =>
```

?

Comment: Yes. Tried, tested and works.  I'm sheepishly aware now that I let the old  code confound me.  Of course I need to use the qualified name!  Many thanks @egilhh